# SUM by month in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2010

Here is my statement in a SQL 2008 View.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    dbo.[Billing Detail].Chart
,   dbo.[Billing Detail].[Transaction Code]
,   SUM(dbo.[Billing Detail].Units) AS [Total Billed]
FROM
    dbo.[Billing Detail]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Patient
    ON dbo.[Billing Detail].Chart = dbo.Patient.[Chart Number]
WHERE
    (dbo.[Billing Detail].[Transaction Code] = 'H2016')
    AND (dbo.[Billing Detail].[Service Date 1] BETWEEN '2013-1-01 00:00:00.000'
                                               AND     '2013-1-31 00:00:000')
GROUP BY
    dbo.[Billing Detail].Chart
,   dbo.[Billing Detail].[Transaction Code]
ORDER BY
    dbo.[Billing Detail].Chart
```

I'm trying to make an IF statement where SUM of Units between 1-1-13 and 1-31-13 out put is JAN, all dates between 2-1-13 and 2-28-13 = FEB...and so on for the rest of the year.  Then I am needing to export this information in to Access 2010 or Excell 2010.

Comment: Why do you have `TOP 100 PERCENT`? Contrary to popular belief, this hack to jam an `ORDER BY` into the view definition does not magically order the output when you select from the view without an `ORDER BY` clause. In fact the query optimizer completely ignores it, so please stop using this syntax.

Comment: @AaronBertrand +1 If only my colleagues would listen to me when I tell them the exact same thing :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think your view should look like. The last two `WHERE` clauses assume you want to hard-code the view to handle the year 2013 only (and [here is why you shouldn't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)). If you want to be able to use the view for any year, just drop those two clauses, and apply them when you select from the view (just like you should be doing with the `ORDER BY`).

```
SELECT
  [month] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, bd.[Service Date 1]), 0),
  bd.Chart,
  bd.[Transaction Code], 
  SUM(bd.Units) AS [Total Billed]
FROM
  dbo.[Billing Detail] AS bd
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Patient AS p
  ON bd.Chart = p.[Chart Number]
WHERE
  bd.[Transaction Code] = 'H2016'
  AND bd.[Service Date 1] >= '20130101'
  AND bd.[Service Date 1] < '20140101'
GROUP BY 
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, bd.[Service Date 1]), 0);
```

Now you're on your own to getting this data into Excel or Access. If it is a one-time task, Excel will pretty much be able to import your results to grid or results to file output. If you need to automate it you can experiment with linked servers to either, but you may be better approaching this from a different angle: linking to the view in Access or having an external application (say, C# command line, PowerShell, etc.) read the results and then output it in the file format you need (.CSV is typically easiest, depending on the data).

Comment: I have a query just like this one, my issue is I need the total billed to be seperate for each month. So the total for transaction code = 'H2016' AND bd.[Service Date 1] >= '20130101'
  AND bd.[Service Date 1] < '20130131'

Comment: is there a way to make this into an IF statement and Update?  I have a query like this one (this one is better), I would like to put it in an IF statement, IF [service date 1] >= date and [service date 1] < date THEN JAN    ELSE IF .....for each month of the year.    Thank you for you'r help.  I've got the Access and Excell part figured out.

Comment: @user2011628 did you run my query? Did you see that the row for January has a sum of the total billed amount for that month only?

Comment: No, `IF` is for control of flow, you can't put `IF` inside a query. Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do without describing it with the method you think you need to do it (e.g. don't use the word `IF` just explain the end result).

Comment: yes I did and I saw where it gave me the total, and i changed the dates for the previous month and received the correct data (thanks)  I'm not a DB person, but our accounting people have asked me to get the billed information (units) for each customer by month that was billed under the (transaction code) H2016. and then for me to put this information either in excell or access for others in accounting to look at to see if the total (units) matches up.  I can pull out the information month by month by manipulating the same query, but i know there has to be an easier way.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Still not sure I understand the problem. You know you can get multiple months by changing the two dates in the WHERE clause, right? Currently it will only get January of 2013 because, well, the start date is January 2013 and you probably don't have any data for future months yet. Try changing the start date to be `20120901` which should get you Sept, Oct, Nov and Dec.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I did not try that. It worked perfectly.  Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Write a query similar to the one you have, that covers the entire date range you want to cover, that groups units on Year and Month (or just Month if you're only covering one year).
2. Export the data to Access or Excel.  You can connect Access to your database tables through ODBC; you can do something similar in Excel, or else use SSMS to export your query results to a CSV file and import it into the tool of your choice. (SSIS would be even better, but if you don't have that, this can still be done.)
3. Using Access or Excel, pivot the data on your Month field into the layout you desire.

While you can use the PIVOT keyword in SQL and get a column for each month, you'll have to do a lot of typing and you won't get any wizard-type guidance.  In Access or Excel, there's an easy-to-use interface to set up your pivot tables and tweak such things as summary rows or subtotals.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to add columns for each of the months and then sum the units for those date ranges?

Assuming so, something like this might work (I've simplified your table structure, but this should get you going in the right direction):

```
SELECT ID, Month, SUM(Units)
FROM (
SELECT  ID, Units, 
    CASE 
       WHEN Month(dt) = 1 THEN 'Jan'
       WHEN Month(dt) = 2 THEN 'Feb'
       WHEN Month(dt) = 3 THEN 'Mar'
    END as Month
FROM         Sample
) t
GROUP BY ID, Month
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c3f2/9).

--EDIT

Actually depending on your desired results, it might be best to include the Year in your WHERE criteria instead of the CASE statement.  Really depends on your data...

```
SELECT ID, Month, SUM(Units)
FROM (
SELECT  ID, Units, 
    CASE 
       WHEN Month(dt) = 1 THEN 'Jan'
       WHEN Month(dt) = 2 THEN 'Feb'
       WHEN Month(dt) = 3 THEN 'Mar'
    END as Month
FROM         Sample
WHERE Year(dt) = 2013
) t
GROUP BY ID, Month
```

Comment: This will lump Jan 2013 with Jan 2012, Jan 2011, etc.

Comment: Yeah, he can Add Year(dt), etc -- or use BETWEEN -- just trying to get the OP going in the right direction :-)

Comment: This worked except it pull all the Units not the Units that were specific to Transaction Code = 'H2016'  I'm trying to add the Where clause now.